# React - setting focus on body element / understanding refs

Tags: reactjs, focus, accessibility, ref

So I'm trying to understand how to move focus when a new page loads in my application. This question came to my mind: what could I do if I want to focus on some element that is somewhere outside of my component. It seems to me that everywhere they write about the focus it's always used with refs. You can pass ref to a child. What if I want to focus on  element to reset the focus on the page when a link is clicked and new page component is loaded? Or if I want to make skip link component higher in the tree and focus on a header in  element? I have a lot of components, it doesn't seem a great idea to pass refs down through several components.

I feel like I'm missing something.
I'm interested about this because I'm learning about accessibility and how to make possible to navigate page only with keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

> what could I do if I want to focus on some element that is somewhere
> outside of my component.
>
> What if I want to focus on element to reset the focus on the page when
> a link is clicked and new page component is loaded?

You can just pass callback of focus handler into your inner component and call it when you want.

Comment: That's right, I can do it like that. Thanks! I think I will use your advice. However I don't like to pass props through many components. I wish there was some easier way.

Comment: I'm not sure that it will be a good approach but I can suggest one more solution. You can use just `useEffect` and `document.getElementById` in it.